# Show calendar to specific users based on custom field

Tags: arrays, calendar, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use the calendar plugin from http://tri.be/ on a worpress website for a private website (it’s like an intranet..).

On this calendar I put all the planned meetings, but I would like that the current logged in user can see only the events he/she is supposed to join.

I thought that I can create a custom field, named, for example, “mustjoin” and put there a list of registered usernames as values.
Then do a check on the page.
If the current logged in username is in that list, he/she can see the event on the calendar.. otherwise not.

Something like :

```
if ( $current_user->user_login == get_field(mustjoin)) { ?>
//CODE IF OK
<?php } else { ?>
//CODE ELSE<?php } ?>
```

This of course is working when I have only one username in the ACF box, as soon as I put more than one username.. it doesn't work anymore because it is not an Array..

How can I create an array with ACF? what function and how can I interrogate that array?

This is the part of the code I need to show IF the current user username is in the value list ‘mustjoin’

```
<?php while ($day['events']->have_posts()) : $day['events']->the_post() ?>
<?php tribe_get_template_part('month/single', 'event') ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

On another forum a guy told me to use this snippet :

```
function searchForName($name, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['nickname'] === $name) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if(searchForName($current_user->user_login,get_field('mustjoin'))):
    //CODE GOES HERE
endif;
```

But it doesn't work..

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump( get_field('mustjoin') );`?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply.
This is what I obtain with the dump :
string(21) "User1 User2 User3"

Thank you.

Comment: Edit : it is string(17) "User1 User2 User3", not 21.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+search+string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comment. This is the code, and it works at 99%.

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>
<?php global $user_login;
      get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
<?php $lookforuser = get_field('mustjoin') ?>
<?php if (strpos($lookforuser, $user_login) !== false) { ?>
    <?php while ($day['events']->have_posts()) : $day['events']->the_post() ?>
    <?php tribe_get_template_part('month/single', 'event') ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But I need to ask you if this code is "clean" or if I can make it better/faster.

Because when I open the calendar page, I can't see anything.. as soon as I refresh the page, all the events (where I am supposed to join) appear.

How can I fix it? (I tried with different computers/browsers, no changes..)
Thank you.

---

Thanks to another guy on another website, finally it works at 100%!
I just needed to check the user before the events loop :

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>
<?php global $user_login;
      get_currentuserinfo(); ?>
<?php while ($day['events']->have_posts()) : $day['events']->the_post(); ?>
   <?php $lookforuser = get_field('mustjoin'); ?>
   <?php if (strpos($lookforuser, $user_login) !== false) 
         tribe_get_template_part('month/single', 'event'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thank you anyway for the right suggestion and help.